# Link inside LI not covering whole LI

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a website but i stumbled upon a little problem i am using a snippet from the bootsnipp (a side menu) i can't get it working so the link will cover the whole LI instead that you have to press the text it self
if i change it so the  will sit before the li it looks off
how can i fix this
Link to snip: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-navigation-menu

My code:
HTML:

```
<div class="nav-side-menu" style="float: left; position: fixed; width: 15.6%;">
<div class="brand"><img alt="Brand" src="includes/img/LogoTest1.png" width="10%"> <b>Craft-List.net</b></div>
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i> 
    <div class="menu-list">
        <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
            <li class="active"><a href="/beta/index"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Members</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Contact</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i> About</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Login/Register</a></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-side-menu {
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #2e353d;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
  background-color: #23282e;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*    
    .collapsed{
       .arrow:before{
                 font-family: FontAwesome;
                 content: "\f053";
                 display: inline-block;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right: 10px;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                 float:right;
            }
     }
*/
}
.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
  background-color: #181c20;
  border: none;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #020203;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .brand {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

The reason why i am asking it here is because that snip looked a bit dead and old lastest comment was 4 months ago.

also i am fairly new to css & html i code more php than design stuff :| anyhow i'd love to see something with a example if that's aksed too mutch plain text will work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @HiddenHobbes yeah i wouldn't dare to forget that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `li` elements have a very thick border of 3px colored `#D19B3D`.  Just taking this `border` out and making the `anchor` tag '`display:block` should help you achieve what you are looking for.

Just for the sake of clarity, I have added a `hover` effect on the `anchor` element to show you that the `anchor` does span the complete width of the `li`.

```css
.nav-side-menu {
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    background-color: #2e353d;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #e1ffff;
}

    .nav-side-menu .brand {
        background-color: #23282e;
        line-height: 50px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-side-menu ul,
    .nav-side-menu li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        line-height: 35px;
        cursor: pointer;
        /*    
    .collapsed{
       .arrow:before{
                 font-family: FontAwesome;
                 content: "\f053";
                 display: inline-block;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right: 10px;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                 float:right;
            }
     }
*/
    }

        .nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
        .nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            content: "\f078";
            display: inline-block;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            float: right;
        }

        .nav-side-menu ul .active,
        .nav-side-menu li .active {
            background-color: #4f5b69;
        }

        .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
        .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
            color: #d19b3d;
        }

            .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
            .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
                color: #d19b3d;
            }

        .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
        .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
            background-color: #181c20;
            border: none;
            line-height: 28px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }

            .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
            .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
                background-color: #020203;
            }

            .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
            .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
                font-family: FontAwesome;
                content: "\f105";
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

    .nav-side-menu li {
        padding-left: 0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
    }

        .nav-side-menu li a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #e1ffff;
        }

        .nav-side-menu li a:hover {
            background-color: orange;
        }

            .nav-side-menu li a i {
                padding-left: 10px;
                width: 20px;
                padding-right: 20px;
            }

        .nav-side-menu li:hover {
            background-color: #4f5b69;
            -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
            -o-transition: all 1s ease;
            -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
            transition: all 1s ease;
        }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav-side-menu {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

        .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 10px;
            z-index: 10 !important;
            padding: 3px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            color: #000;
            width: 40px;
            text-align: center;
        }

    .brand {
        text-align: left !important;
        font-size: 22px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        line-height: 50px !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
    .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
        display: block;
    }
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-side-menu" style="float: left; position: fixed; width: 15.6%;">
<div class="brand"><img alt="Brand" src="includes/img/LogoTest1.png" width="10%"> <b>Craft-List.net</b></div>
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i> 
    <div class="menu-list">
        <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
            <li class="active"><a href="/beta/index"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Members</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Contact</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i> About</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Login/Register</a></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: This cleared up a lot for me :D thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have to put a `display: block;` to the `a` element, wich has `display: inline;` as default.

```
.nav-side-menu li a {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: That is not working :( and just for the sake of testing i tried to use the display: inline; too byt not working :(

Comment: It was my cache annoying me this time your's in combination with @Satwik Nadkarny helped me fixing this :D